# Comprimir contenido carpeta en ZIP con C++

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, serialización, zip

Llevo unas semanas tratando de lograr una compresión de archivos (de cualquier tipo) dentro de un zip a partir de una entrada de un archivo zip con su ruta y la ruta de donde se va a descomprimir, que les paso como parámetros (--input y --output)

Dado que C++ de forma nativa no incorpora ningún método para ello, he obtado por usar la libreria: Ziplib[Wiki](https://bitbucket.org/wbenny/ziplib/wiki/Home) que se supone que te facilita enormemente esta tarea.

Yo trato de seguir los pasos tal como pone la documentación de la libreria que es los siguientes:

```
ZipArchive::Ptr archive = ZipFile::Open("archive.zip");

  ZipArchiveEntry::Ptr entry = archive->CreateEntry("file.dat");

  // if entry is nullptr, it means the file already exists in the archive
  assert(entry != nullptr); 

  std::ifstream contentStream("file.dat", std::ios::binary); //should not be destroyed before archive is written
  entry->SetCompressionStream(contentStream);

  // you may of course save it somewhere else
  // note: the contentStream is pumped when the archive is saved
  // if you want to read the stream before saving of the archive,
  // it is need to set Immediate mode in SetCompressionStream method (see below)
  ZipFile::SaveAndClose(archive, "archive.zip");


  // If you want to use std::ostream interface for custom purposes
  // such as sending data over network, where no seek() operation possible
  // or you want to remove unnecessary seek operations on HDD
  // mark entry to use data descriptor for pure streamed operation
  // see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zip_(file_format)#File_headers
  // entry->UseDataDescriptor(true); 
  // archive->WriteToStream(std::ostream);
```

Sin embargo al traducirlo a mi código, y crear una primera aproximación bruta, simplemente añadiendole un archivo (para no lidiar con la parte de recursividad de carpetas y subcarpetas), no es capaz de añadir el archivo como entrada al objeto `ZipFile::Ptr` donde se supone que debo ir metiendo las diferentes entradas.

El error que me muestra, que no entiendo demasiado bien, es en la última línea de `main()`, con el `return 0`. Y cuando trato de ir a ver el output del Zip, veo que pesa 0Kb y al intentar abrirlo me muestra un mensaje de error diciéndome que el archivo está corrupto o dañado.

[image: Error de memoria dentro de Visual Studio 2019 al compilar el código de programa]

Es algo muy extraño, dado que mi ejemplo de la parte de compresión funciona bien (lo que descarta que pueda estar pillando mal las rutas de los archivos o que el SO tenga los permisos de escritura / lectura denegados)

Añado por último la parte correspondiente a mi código de la descompresión:

```
   // Se le pasa el archivo zip donde se va a comprimir (Se debe crear previamente)

    ZipArchive::Ptr archive = ZipFile::Open(parameters.output_path);

    if (!archive)
    {
        exit ("ERROR: failed to open the input folder archive.");
    }

    // Se crea un buffer en el que se leerá el contenido de cada archivo antes de escribirlo.
    // Se crea aquí para que lo compartan todos los archivos.

    std::vector< char > buffer;

    // Se añade un separador a la carpeta de destino para facilitar la concatenación:

    replace(parameters.output_path.begin(), parameters.output_path.end(), '\\', '/');

    parameters.output_path.push_back (filesystem::path::preferred_separator);

    // Se añaden los datos de entrada
   
    ZipArchiveEntry::Ptr entry = archive->CreateEntry(parameters.input_path);

    // Se comprueba que la entrada no es nula

    assert(entry != nullptr);

    // Se crea un objeto de ifstream de la libreria estandar para leer el fichero

    std::ifstream contentStream;
    contentStream.open(parameters.input_path, std::ios::binary);

    assert(contentStream.is_open());

    entry->SetCompressionStream(contentStream);

    // Se guarda y cierra el Zip

    cout << "Archivos totales anidados: " << archive->GetEntriesCount() << endl;
    cout << "Done." << endl;

    ZipFile::SaveAndClose(archive, parameters.output_path);
```

Agradecería cualquier tipo de ayuda, dado que llevo varias semanas peleándome con ello. Incluso si conoceis alguna otra manera de hacerlo más sencilla o otra librería abierta similar para Windows, que me pueda servir para resolver el problema.

Un saludo